# where can i download TelnetClient for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've found a source for telnet for eclipse but the directory of telnet import is empty 
where can i find this item to download
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/remote-system-explorer-ssh-telnet-ftp-and-dstore-protocols
Just drag the little Install button onto your eclipse.

Comment: I;ve downloaded apache-commons-net.jar but idon't know how to use it

Comment: also i checked this site, but find not more